# Understand deinitialization and inheritance in swift language

Tags: inheritance, swift

Let's say I have two classes: Base class and sub class like this:

```
class Base{
    var name: String?
    init() {
       name = "The base class"
    }

    deinit {
       println("call Deinitialization in base class")
       name = nil
    }
}

class Sub: Base{
    var subName: String?
    init() {
     super.init()
     subName = "The sub class"
    }

    deinit {
       println("call Deinitialization in sub class")
       subName = nil
       // does it really call super.deinit() ?
       // or assign name = nil ?
    }
}
```

When the deinitializer of sub class is called, does it call `super.deinit()` to assign nil to `name` variable? Or I have to assign by hand in deinitializer  of subclass?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can optionally have a `deinit` inside your subclass.

If you do

```
    let x = Sub()
```

you'll see that first the `deinit` called is the one inside `Sub()` then after, `base` `deinit` is called. So yes the `super.deinit()` is called but after the subclass.

Also the book says (page 286):

> You are not allowed to call a deinitializer yourself. Superclass deinitializers are inherited by their subclasses, and the superclass
>   deinitializer is called automatically at the end of a subclass
>   deinitializer implementation. Superclass deinitializers are always
>   called, even if a subclass does not provide its own deinitializer.

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/us/jEUH0.l

Answer (score 8):

> Superclass deinitializers are inherited by their subclasses, and the
>   superclass deinitializer is called automatically at the end of a
>   subclass deinitializer implementation. Superclass deinitializers are
>   always called, even if a subclass does not provide its own
>   deinitializer.

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/us/jEUH0.l